# Classpath и сборщики(maven,ant,gradle)

Tags: java, maven, classloader

Доброго дня, уважаемые разработчики
Недавно решил доразобраться с темой Classpath, смотрел несколько публикаций на эту тему. в частности http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-classpath-unix/ и http://www.skipy.ru/technics/likbez.html
но из материалов так и не понял как эти знания фактически могут быть применены при разработке. Могу ли я что-то полезное получить из статей если использую среду разработки например IDEA(Eclipse). Примеры, которые приведены в статьях ничего не говорят о том, нужно ли отдельно настаивать Classpath, когда проект собирается сборщиком, например Maven. Насколько я понимаю Maven все эти вещи прописывает автоматически, а значит прямо повлиять на настройки. Можете ли Вы привести примеры из работы, когда понимание Classpath непосредственно повлияло на разработку?

Answer (score 3):

С одной стороны `CLASSPATH` это такая штука без понимания которого невозможно стать нормальным девелопером, с другой стороны все IDE и автоматические сборщики обычно так хорошо маскируют `CLASSPATH`, что явное его использование скорее исключение нежели правило.

Наверное хороший тон, когда `CLASSPATH` явно не задается в виде переменной окружения (на этапе разработки). На этом этапе, в 99% `CLASSPATH` передается компилятору в виде параметра `-cp` или подобным способом через настроечные файлы и проч. Дело в том, что задание `CLASSPATH` в виде явной переменной среды не портабельно, а поскольку программирование труд коллективный, то нужно стремиться к тому, чтобы после *checkout* из VCS/репо все работало сразу без задания дополнительных шаманских танцев вокруг переменных среды и проч.

Танцы с бубнами вокруг `CLASSPATH` обычно начинаются в продакшн окружении, все что раньше работало перестает работать, поскольку ранее это была забота IDE. Но в продакшне уже нет IDE и надо заставить работать jar/war/ear без привычного окружения. Вот тут и начинается - выясняется, что какой-нибудь поганый JDBC драйвер должен лежать в специальном каталоге сервера или WAR надо разворачивать именно так, а не иначе - тут конечно без понимания что такое `CLASSPATH` и как это работает никак не обойтись.